# python __import__ from same folder fails

Tags: python, import, importerror

I have a directory structure like so:

```
|- project
  |- commands.py
  |- Modules
  | |- __init__.py
  | |- base.py
  | \- build.py
  \- etc....
```

I have the following code in `__init__.py`

```
commands = []
hooks = []

def load_modules():
    """ dynamically loads commands from the /modules subdirectory """
    path = "\\".join(os.path.abspath(__file__).split("\\")[:-1])
    modules = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(".py") and f != "__init__.py"]
    print modules
    for file in modules:
        try:
            module = __import__(file.split(".")[0])
            print module
            for obj_name in dir(module):
                try:
                    potential_class = getattr(module, obj_name)
                    if isinstance(potential_class, Command):
                        #init command instance and place in list
                        commands.append(potential_class(serverprops))
                    if isinstance(potential_class, Hook):
                        hooks.append(potential_class(serverprops))
                except:
                    pass
        except ImportError as e:
            print "!! Could not load %s: %s" % (file, e)
    print commands
    print hooks
```

I'm trying to get `__init__.py` to load the appropriate commands and hooks into the lists given, however i always hit an ImportError at `module = __import__(file.split(".")[0])` even though `__init__.py` and base.py etc are all in the same folder. i have verified that nothing in any of the module files requires anything in `__init__.py`, so i'm really at a loss of what to do.

Comment: `__import__` has quite a few fiddly bits you need to be aware of, especially to do with `fromlist`. Try searching for that and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: `path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` (more correct and incidentally cross-platform)

Comment: From where and how is `load_modules()` invoked?

Comment: load_modules is invoked from commands.py during init

Answer (score 2):

All you're missing is having Modules on the system path. Add

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path)
```

after your `path = ...` line and you should be set. Here's my test script:

```
import os, os.path, sys

print '\n'.join(sys.path) + '\n' * 3

commands = []
hooks = []

def load_modules():
    """ dynamically loads commands from the /modules subdirectory """
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    print "In path:", path in sys.path
    sys.path.append(path)

    modules = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(".py") and f != "__init__.py"]
    print modules
    for file in modules:
        try:
            modname = file.split(".")[0]
            module = __import__(modname)
            for obj_name in dir(module):
                print '%s.%s' % (modname, obj_name )
        except ImportError as e:
            print "!! Could not load %s: %s" % (file, e)
    print commands


load_modules()
```